# Define command that executes several functions

Tags: functions, commands, kill-ring

I apologize for this question, for which I know an elementary answer exists that I can't find for the life of me. I would simply like to define a command that executes several functions sequentially. Concretely I want to make a command `kill-append` that does first `append-next-kill`, then kills the marked region. I've written the following:

```lisp
(defun kill-append ()
  (interactive)
  (append-next-kill)
  (kill-region (mark) (point)))
```

but when I execute it, I get an error message

```
kill-region: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda nil (interactive) (append-next-kill) (kill-region (mark) (point))), 2
```

which I think comes from the fact that `defun` expects its body to consist of one expression, not a list. I know there is an easy command that allows one to do this, but when searching I only encountered solutions for specific cases, such as using advice (which doesn't fit here since I don't want to modify `append-next-kill`, only define a new function from it) or macros (which gives me an error message because I'm applying the Meta-modifier using `event-apply-meta-modifier` which it doesn't seem to like for some reason). I've seen a general method to do this a while ago but can't find it again and it was an unituitive command name that I don't remember. Now I would really like to know the general solution for this so I have it in my code and can look it up whenever I need it again.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: No, the body of a `defun` is an implicit `progn`. It does *not* "expects it body to consist of one expression, not a list".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `defun`, except that when you evaluate it, it would clobber the existing function `kill-append`. The trouble is that `kill-append` is called by `kill-region`, but it is called with two arguments (because it thinks it's calling the original `kill-append` which does take two arguments) - since the new `kill-append` takes no arguments, Emacs complains loudly.

Note that `defun` allows a sequence of forms in its body, so there is no need for any grouping (which you would do with `progn`, but there is no need to do that here).

So the problem is that you clobber an existing function. The solution is to be careful with names: first check if there is something by that name already defined, by using `C-h f kill-append`, and if there is, use a different name, since you never know whether some other function will be calling `kill-append` expecting to find the old function and getting the new one instead.
A useful convention is to name your function with a prefix that is unlikely to be used by anybody else: e.g. in this case, some people would call the new function `my/kill-append` or `my-kill-append` - my preference is to use part of my name as a prefix with a `/` as separator, e.g. `ndk/kill-append` or, in your case, `apr/kill-append` perhaps.

So the following should work:

```el
(defun apr/kill-append ()
  (interactive)
  (append-next-kill)
  (kill-region (mark) (point)))
```

This name does not conflict with an existing name (I checked with `C-h f apr/TAB` to make sure there is no function with an `apr/` prefix in its name), so it does not interfere with `kill-region`'s ability to call the old function with the proper number of arguments.